# ApiResource returns "invalid_scope" identityserver

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid

I am implementing Identity Server in a razor page application.

When requesting the `speech` ApiResource, identityserver returns "invalid_scope". My understanding is that the resource is a group of scopes. So, I was expecting the identityserver to return the scopes defined in the speech resource.
Note: Which I add `speech` as ApiScope it works fine but then it does not add the `speech.synthesize` and `payment.subscription` scopes.

Here's how I have defined the ApiScopes:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
        new List<ApiScope>
        {
            new ApiScope("speech.synthesize", "Speech synthesis",new []{"api.create" }),
            new ApiScope("payment.subscription", "Subscription service"),
            new ApiScope("payment.manage", "Manage Payment"),
        };
```

And here's how I have defined the ApiResource:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
        new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("speech", "Speech API")
            {
                Scopes = { "speech.synthesize", "payment.subscription" }
            }
        };
```

And here's the client configuration:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",

                // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,

                // secret for authentication
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                // scopes that client has access to
                AllowedScopes = {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    "speech"
                }
            }
        };
```

What is wrong here? Can anybody help me understand the problem.

**What is the role of the Api Resource if not grouping the scopes.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You as a client asks for ApiScopes, not ApiResources. One more more ApiResource can point to an ApiScope.

An ApiResource represents an API instance, not a Scope. ApiResources are like clients, but for Apis.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811157/apiresource-vs-apiscope-vs-identityresource/63812939#63812939) for more details about the difference between IdentityResource, ApiResource and ApiScope

Comment: So, Api Resource controls the list of scopes that can be sent to an actual API resource. After reading your answer I remembered that the ApiResource is used in the Resource Server as "Audience".

Comment: Your client asks for a set of scopes (Either IdentityResources or ApiScopes). ApiScopes can then give access to one or multiple Apis (ApiResources). and the aud claim in the access-token will contain the list of ApiRsources associated with the ApiScopes selected.

Comment: As per the https://stackoverflow.com/a/63058736/9522887 the audience claim is no longer sent and not configured in the Resource Owner. Does that mean ApiResource is no longer suggested?

Comment: In version 4, they introduced the ApiScope and rearchitected how these things work with ApiResources. You do want this and you want the audience claim as the AddJwtBearer API's ues that to verify that the token they receive is intended for them.

Comment: But as you can see in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/63058736/9522887 answer there is no Audience. And it is using AddJwtBearer(). Is it incorrect config?

Comment: You get a proper audience if you define ApiScope and ApiResoures, otherwise you will get an generic static audience claim instead. See this page https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/resources/api_scopes/

Unless you disable it, I think it will do an audience check even if its not in the code. But you should use Audience to make a secure API, its a best practice.